# Is it possible to view google user login activity with this SDK

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I am working with the Admin SDK and am interested in working with the account activity information that Google provides when you click on the "last account activity" details link on the lower right corner of Gmail. I would like to see what IPs people are logging in from.

I am not seeing anything in the docs. Am I overlooking something? Is there a better API to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the [directory.user.get()](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users) function and the [reports.userUsageReports()](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/usage-ref-appendix-a/users) function provide last login information but neither supplies IP addresses.

The only way to get IP address information is using the Email Audit API [account activity function](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/email-audit/#accessing_account_information).